# Find ONE value that is in A but not in B

Tags: matlab

Assuming I have

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
B = [1 2 4 5 8];
```

I want to find ONE value that is in A but not in B. I could do the following:

```
temp  = setdiff(A,B);
if ~isempty(temp)
  myValue = temp(1);
else
  myValue = [];
end
```

But is there a faster way, since I only need ONE value and not all of them? Efficiency is important :)

Comment: Are `A` and `B` always sorted?

Comment: A is always sorted, in fact, it is always 1:size(input,1). B unfortunately is not always sorted, only in chuncks, that is B might look like this: B = [1 2 9 19 3 4 5 6]; Expected size of is A about 20000 and B is always smaller than A.

Comment: You should check [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/53796-speed-up-intersect-setdiff-functions) out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `A` is `1:n`, the first value of `B` that is not in `A` is where the difference between sorted elements of `B` is bigger than 1.

```
sortedB = sort(B);

firstMissingValue = find(diff([0,sortedB,size(A,1)])>1,1,'first');
```

Comment: yes, sweet! In this particular case this works and is slightly faster also than MY_setdiff from patriks link. However, you have to take diff([0,sortedB, size(A,1)] )

Comment: @user1809923 You're welcome, and thanks for the addition of the last value in A. Note that this will not find values of B that are larger than the largest value of A if there are no "missing" values in B.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try that? For me it was faster, maybe you can try it.

```
a=ismember(A,B); 
if sum(a)~=0
   myValue = A(a);
   myValue = myValue(1);
else
   myValue =  [];
end
```

Comment: hey! You would have to put a = ~ismember(A,B). Also I think instead of sum(a) ~= 0, any(a) should be faster. In my testings however this did not improve speed compared to setdiff.

Comment: The functions `ismember` and `setdiff` are quite similar, so if you are looking for improving performance over the `setdiff` solution this is probably a dead end.